# unity - how to turn pushcart to drop fruits to ground

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this scene:

[image]

My goal is to player push bricks and then the Pushcart turn to ground and the baskets above drop the fruits on the ground.

I made everything rigidbody, but when player remove the bricks, the Push cart stays at same position, instead turning to ground.

One thing I tried is add an invisible rigidbody cube above it, but didn't worked.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show the colliders involved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a Collider to the pushcart?

Also, what are the settings on the RididBody? Maybe try resetting those to default values and see what happens.